# Tab Autocomplete does not work in windows CMD when remoting into machine using WINRS - WINRM

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, autocomplete, winrm

When inside a basic windows `cmd` prompt doing something like `cd <TAB>` will start auto-completion; However, when I connect to a remote machine using `winrs` the `<TAB>` key simply inserts a tab character. No auto-completion.

If I remote desktop into the same machine and open a basic `cmd` auto-completion works so I think it is something specific to my `winrs` connection.

Is it possible to achieve auto-completion while in a `winrs` remote connection? If so how can I achieve this?

Here is the command used to initiate the remote connection.

```
winrs -r:REMOTE_HOST -u:USER_NAME cmd
```